# Simplifying convariance and contravariance implementation

Tags: c#-4.0, covariance, contravariance

Implementing independent scheduler class i had to come to the following interface:

```
public interface ISchedulableContext<in T1, out T2> where T1: T2, ISchedulerConfigProvider
{
    void LogMessage(LoggingEventLevel level, string eventName, string Message);
    void Process(ISchedulerConfigProvider schedulerConfig);
    IEnumerable<T2> GetSchedulerConfig();
    void SaveUpdatedConfig(IEnumerable<T1> schedulers);
}
```

It works but does require explicit and redundant specifying and passing of type ISchedulableContext<ISchedulerConfigProvider,ISchedulerConfigProvider>

```
public class SchedulableCore: ISchedulableContext<ISchedulerConfigProvider,ISchedulerConfigProvider>
{ 
...
}

public class TaskScheduler
{
    private ISchedulableContext<ISchedulerConfigProvider, ISchedulerConfigProvider> core;

    public TaskScheduler(ISchedulableContext<ISchedulerConfigProvider, ISchedulerConfigProvider> core)
    {
        this.core = core;
    }
}
```

I would like to simplify this realisation and use simple interface implementing instead:

```
public class SchedulableCore: ISchedulableContext
{ 
    /*...*/
    public IEnumerable<ISchedulerConfigProvider> GetSchedulerConfig()
    {
        return (IEnumerable<ISchedulerConfigProvider>)/*...*/;
    }

    public void SaveUpdatedConfig(IEnumerable<ISchedulerConfigProvider> schedulers)
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

Is it possible to simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the interface as the type-parameter, you can use the interface itself *instead* of type parameters:

```
public interface ISchedulableContext {
  void LogMessage(LoggingEventLevel level, string eventName, string Message);
  void Process(ISchedulerConfigProvider schedulerConfig);
  IEnumerable<ISchedulerConfigProvider> GetSchedulerConfig();
  void SaveUpdatedConfig(IEnumerable<ISchedulerConfigProvider> schedulers);
}
```

Note that this is not equivalent to what you've posted. In your example, `T2` can be something different than a `ISchedulerConfigProvider`, but `T1` must adhere to it. Also, the `Process` method is not using any type-parameter (and it looks like it should). It's not entirely clear to me why that's the case. If this is intentional, maybe you could provide some explanation.

Another option is to provide just one invariant type parameter:

```
public interface ISchedulableContext<T> where T : ISchedulerConfigProvider {
  void LogMessage(LoggingEventLevel level, string eventName, string Message);
  void Process(T schedulerConfig);
  IEnumerable<T> GetSchedulerConfig();
  void SaveUpdatedConfig(IEnumerable<T> schedulers);
}
```

Yet another option is to segregate the interface into two: one for the covariant methods on `T`, another for the contravariant ones.

Comment: T2 is supposed to be an ISchedulerConfigProvider also.
Big thank you! I just took your first example and it works :)